# Why setContentOffset does not work in scrollViewDidEndDragging method?

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to do something like Clear app does: when you drag to top, a new cell appears and it remains on top of table view (I think with setContentOffset). The problem is, when I try to set table view content offset in method scrollViewDidEndDragging (or any other like this) it doesn't work. Basically content offset setting is ignored. My code is like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    [_myTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -100) animated:YES];
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: _myTableView and ScrollView are different view ?

Comment: No, they're not. _myTableView has as delegate "self", so this method should recognize it.

Comment: Hi. check out my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27088865/1510171

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate   { 
    [_myTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -100) animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Content offset appears set well for a moment, but it becomes as before then :/

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3.0**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { in  
   _myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -100), animated: true)  
}
```

Comment: Also you can use `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating` func instead of `scrollViewDidEndDragging`